# I need to show a warning message below input when mat-toogle-button is YES?

Tags: angular

I need to show a message below the input tag when user selects YES in mat-toggle-button.

If Certification Required is "Yes"
Certification Version will be a required entry
Certification Fulfilled will be a required entry

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="label-icon "><label class="required"><b>Certification Required</b></label>
                    <!--<span><i class="material-icons info-icon">info_outline</i></span>-->
                </div>
                <div>
                    <mat-button-toggle-group  name="certRqrd" #certificationReq="ngModel" #group="matButtonToggleGroup"
                        [(ngModel)]="modalData.certificationReq" (change)="certRqrChange()" id="certificationReq" 
                        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': ModalForm.submitted && certificationReq.invalid }">
                        <mat-button-toggle [value]="true"  [disableRipple]="true" >Yes</mat-button-toggle>
                        <mat-button-toggle [value]="false" [disableRipple]="true" >No</mat-button-toggle>
                    </mat-button-toggle-group>
                    <div *ngIf="ModalForm.submitted && certificationReq.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="ModalForm.submitted && certificationReq.errors?.required">This field is
                            required
                        </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
             </div>
            <div class="col">
               <div class="label-icon"> <label> <b>Certification Version </b></label> </div>
                <input type="text" name="certVer" [(ngModel)]="modalData.certVer" placeholder="Certification Version" [required]="modalData.certificationReq">
             </div>

               <div class="col">
                   <div>
                        <label class="label-icon"><b>Certification Fulfilled</b></label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <mat-button-toggle-group name="certRqrdd"  #group="matButtonToggleGroup"
                            [(ngModel)]="modalData.certFulFld">
                            <mat-button-toggle [value]="true" >Yes</mat-button-toggle>
                            <mat-button-toggle [value]="false" >No</mat-button-toggle>
                        </mat-button-toggle-group>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz demo? Also you can use `modalData.certFulFld` to check that is the user is checked the toggle or unchecked and based on that show error message

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhnazs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

can you check it.
I need to display a warning message below the input when certification required is yes.
message has to be such as "this field requires entry"

Comment: have you tried posted answer?

Comment: yes,

but it is disappering from UI if i write if condtion.
below it my ts code for the method I used.
 certRqrChange() {
        console.log('this.modalData.certificationReq',this.modalData.certificationReq);
        if (this.modalData.certificationReq === false) {
            this.modalData.certVer = "None";
            this.modalData.certFulFld = true;
        } else {
            this.modalData.certVer = '';
            this.modalData.certFulFld = '';
        }
      }

Comment: Okay then provide your code in the stacblitz where  can reproduce an issue

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pj7jsv

Answer (score 0):

You can add `*ngIf` condition for that.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="modalData.certFulFld">
    <div> Message </div>
<ng-container>
```

Comment: it is disappering from ui if i change the certificationversion to yes

Comment: @rohitsiriga Could you provide demo on stackblitz?